# How to copy/sync music downloaded from Apple Music on iTunes to iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, music

I have Apple Music subscription. When I make songs available offline(on iPhone 5s) I can listen to them on the device that I downloaded the songs without internet and not offline on iTunes on my Desktop running Windows 10.

If i make music available offline on computer then I can listen to them only on computer without internet and not on my iPhone. I have to re-download the music onto my iPhone.

I'm using the same apple account. All my songs are getting downloaded twice. What should I do to copy the music from Desktop to iPhone without redownloading?

### Hardware

- iPhone 5S - iOS 9.1
- Windows 10 - 64 bit

Why should I have to download a song on each device when I'm signed in on the same Apple account?

Also, when I add a song to Apple Music, It comes under my music from my iPhone and also to itunes my music in computer, but i have to make the music available offline again even if i did download on to the phone earlier. *The offline music does not sync.*

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Could you help us help you by editing this to have a clearer end question.  It would be best if you could link to an Apple support article showing exactly what you want to accomplish and why you're not able to figure out your specific situation.

Comment: Well your iPhone's storage is separate from your computer, so you'll have to download it to each device. Not sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: i'm not trying to accomplish anything just wanna resolve it. i know they r two. but i tunes are one no matter where r u signed in from. when i add to my music from any device it comes on both devices where i singed in with same login details. but have to download on each device. and i don't see my question off topic.as i've seen many questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't sync Apple Music downloaded content from iTunes to your iPhone (or the other way round). Each device has to download it separately (as of iOS 11.3 and iTunes 12.7.3).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to re-download the track to iTunes on the computer. You can just connect the iPhone over USB and play the music that's on the iPhone.

If you want the track to be cached on the PC (or any other iTunes), then you do need to allow the track to download.

Comment: I think he is asking that If he has downloaded the music on the iTunes on Desktop ( via Apple Music Subscription ), How can he sync those offline music onto the iPhone (without having to download them again on the phone)

Comment: @JashJacob I keyed on "even if I did download on to the phone earlier" text and since you can easily play from iPhone, that's the best option. You can't sync the other way from e play cache afaik on the current versions of iOS and iTunes.